# Form just gets data from first row in table

Tags: php, html

I´m having some problems while doing the following, I´m going to try to explain clear what my problem is. I have an HTML table with lots of rows,... and I´m using an HTML form with a button that when you click on it, it sends information to another PHP Script, and it´s working fine, except that it justs gets the information of the first row, no matter where else you click it always sends the data of the first row, this is what I have tried so far:

```
<?php
$pilotid = Auth::$userinfo->pilotid;
$last_location = RealScheduleLiteData::get_pilot_location($pilotid, 1);
$last_name = OperationsData::getAirportInfo($last_location->arricao);
$biddata = SchedulesData::GetBid($sched_data->bidid);
?>
<h3><b>Job Offers</b></h3>

<ul>

</ul>

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" class="table table-striped m0 p0 mt0" style="table-layout:fixed;">
    <tr class="table-header">
        <td colspan="6">Available jobs from <?php echo $last_location->arricao.' ( '.$last_name->name.')' ;?></td>
    </tr>

<?php
if(!$allroutes)
{
?>
    <tr><td align="center">No flights from <?php echo $last_location->arricao.' ( '.$last_name->name.')' ;?>!</td></tr>

<?php
}
else
{
?>
<script src="http://skyvector.com/linkchart.js"></script>


    <tr class="table-header">
    <th width="10%" align="center">Airline</th>
    <th width="10%" align="center">Flight ID</th>
    <th width="10%" align="center">Departure</th>
    <th width="10%" align="center">Arrival</th>
    <th width="10%" align="center">Aircraft</th>
    <th width="30%" colspan=1" align="left">Options</th>
</tr>

<?php
foreach($allroutes as $route)
{
    if(Config::Get('DISABLE_SCHED_ON_BID') == true && $route->bidid != 0)
    {
        continue;
    }
    if(Config::Get('RESTRICT_AIRCRAFT_RANKS') === true && Auth::LoggedIn())
    {
        if($route->aircraftlevel > Auth::$userinfo->ranklevel)
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
?>

<tr class="table-data">
        <td width="20%" align="left" valign="middle"><?php echo '<img src="'.fileurl('/airlines/'.$route->code.'.png').'" alt="'.$airline->name.'" />'; ?></td>
    <td width="20%" align="left" valign="middle"><?php echo $route->code . $route->flightnum?></td>
    <td width="20%" align="left" valign="middle"><?php echo $route->depicao ;?></td>
    <td width="20%" align="left" valign="middle"><?php echo $route->arricao ;?></td>
    <td width="20%" align="left" valign="middle"><?php echo $route->aircraft ;?></td>
        <td width="20%" align="left" valign="middle"><input type="button" value="Job Description" onclick="$('#details_dialog_<?php echo $route->flightnum;?>').toggle()">
        <form id="sbapiform">

        <input type="button" onclick="simbriefsubmit('http://www.virtualaviationgroup.com/index.php/SimBrief');" style="font-size:14px" value="Generate Flight Plan">
<table>
    <tr>
       <?php $planedata=(OperationsData::getAircraftByReg($route->registration)) ;?>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="type" size="5" type="text" placeholder="ZZZZ"  value="<?php echo $planedata->icao ;?>"></td>
    <tr>

    <tr>
         <td><input type="hidden" name="orig" size="5" type="text" placeholder="ZZZZ" maxlength="4" value="<?php echo $route->depicao ; ?>"></td>
    <tr>

    <tr>
       <td><input type="hidden" name="dest" size="5" type="text" placeholder="ZZZZ" maxlength="4" value="<?php echo $route->arricao ; ?>"></td>
    <tr>

    <tr>
       <td><input type="hidden" name="route" placeholder="Enter your route here"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan=2></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
       <td><input type="hidden" name="units" size="5" type="text" placeholder="ZZZZ" maxlength="4" value="KGS"></td>
    </tr>

</table>


<input type="hidden" name="airline" value="<?php echo $route->code?>"> 

<input type="hidden" name="fltnum" value="<?php echo $route->flightnum?>"> 

<?php $today = date("dMy");?>

<input type="hidden" name="date" value="<?php echo $today?>"> 

<?php $deptimes = explode(":", $route->deptime); ?>

<input type="hidden" name="deph" value="<?php echo $deptimes[0]?>">
<input type="hidden" name="depm" value="<?php echo $deptimes[1]?>">    

<?php $arrtimes = explode(":", $route->arrtime); ?>

<input type="hidden" name="steh" value="<?php echo $arrtimes[0]?>">
<input type="hidden" name="stem" value="<?php echo $arrtimes[1]?>">



<input type="hidden" name="reg" value="<?php echo $route->registration?>">    


 <input type="hidden" name="navlog" value="1"> 
<input type="hidden" name="selcal" value="GR-FS">    

<input type="hidden" name="planformat" value="lido">





</form>


       <?php 
        if($biddata->pilotid == $pilotid && $route->bidid != 0)
        {
        ?>
        <input type="button" value="You´re Hired!"
        <?php
        }
        else
        {
        ?>
        <a id="<?php echo $route->id; ?>" class="addbid" href="<?php echo url('/schedules/addbid');?>"><input type="button" value="Accept Job"</a>
        <?php                    
        }
        ?>

    </td>
</tr>

        <td colspan="6">

        <table cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10" border="0" class="table table-striped m0 p0 mt0" id="details_dialog_<?php echo $route->flightnum;?>" style="display:none" width="100%">

            <tr>
            <th align="left" colspan="4">Flight Brefing</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td align="left">&nbsp&nbspDeaprture:</td>
            <td colspan="0" align="left" ><b>&nbsp&nbsp<?php
            $name = OperationsData::getAirportInfo($route->depicao);
            echo "{$name->name}"?></b></td>
            <td align="left">&nbsp&nbspArrival:</td>
            <td colspan="0" align="left" ><b>&nbsp&nbsp<?php 
            $name = OperationsData::getAirportInfo($route->arricao);
            echo "{$name->name}"?></b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td align="left">&nbsp&nbspAircraft</td>
            <td colspan="0" align="left" ><b>&nbsp&nbsp<?php 
            $plane = OperationsData::getAircraftByName($route->aircraft);
            echo $plane->fullname ; ?></b></td>
            <td align="left">&nbsp&nbspDistance:</td>
            <td colspan="0" align="left" ><b>&nbsp&nbsp<?php echo $route->distance . Config::Get('UNITS') ;?></b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td align="left">&nbsp&nbspDep Time:</td>
            <td colspan="0" align="left" ><b>&nbsp&nbsp<?php echo $route->deptime?> GMT</font></b></td>
            <td align="left">&nbsp&nbspArr Time:</td>
            <td colspan="0" align="left" ><b>&nbsp&nbsp<?php echo $route->arrtime?> GMT</font></b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td align="left">&nbsp&nbspAltitude:</td>
            <td colspan="0" align="left" ><b>&nbsp&nbsp<?php echo $route->flightlevel; ?> ft</b></td>
            <td align="left">&nbsp&nbspDuration:</td>
            <td colspan="0" align="left" ><b>&nbsp
            <?php 

            $dist = $route->distance;
            $speed = 440;
            $app = $speed / 60 ;
            $flttime = round($dist / $app,0)+ 20;
            $hours = intval($flttime / 60);
            $minutes = (($flttime / 60) - $hours) * 60;
            if($hours > "9" AND $minutes > "9")
            {
            echo $hours.':'.$minutes ;
            }
            else
            {
            echo '0'.$hours.':0'.$minutes ;
            }
            ?> Hrs</b></font></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

            <tr>
            <td align="left">&nbsp&nbspFlight Type:</td>
            <td colspan="0" align="left" ><b>&nbsp&nbsp<?php
            if($route->flighttype == "P")
            {
            echo'Passenger' ;
            }
            if($route->flighttype == "C")
            {
            echo'Cargo' ;
            }
            if($route->flighttype == "H")
            {
            echo'Charter' ;
            }
            ?></b></td>
            <td align="left">&nbsp&nbspFlown</td>
            <td colspan="0" align="left" ><b>&nbsp&nbsp<?php echo $route->timesflown ;?></b></td>
            </tr>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th align="center"colspan="4">Flight Map</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td width="100%" colspan="4">
            <?php
            $string = "";
                        $string = $string.$route->depicao.'+-+'.$route->arricao.',+';
                        ?>
<img width="100%" src="http://www.gcmap.com/map?P=<?php echo $string ?>&amp;MS=wls2&MR;MR=240&amp;MX=680x200&amp;PM=pemr:diamond7:red%2b%22%25I%22:red&amp;PC=%230000ff" />


</div>

</tr>
</td>
         </table>   

        </td>
</tr>


<?php
}
}
?>
</table>
<br />
<hr>
<br />

<center><a href="<?php echo url('/FrontSchedules') ;?>"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Back to Flight Booking System" ></a></center>
```

I´m sorry guys if this question is not good enough, or it´s already asked, I could not find anything simillar to this. Please don´t be rude with me

Kind Regards!!

--EDIT--

I have these table(which I´m not showing in the code, because it has nothing to do with these)

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOoSS.png)

And each time you click on the button "Generate Flight Plan" it calls the function sending all the variables that I show in the code... The problem is that is just works for the 1st flight shown there. Because if you click in the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th.... whatever it sends the data of the 1st one.

Comment: it seems you are executing a function onclick="simbriefsubmit('http://www.virtualaviationgroup.com/index.php/SimBrief');"  for submit so show that function code the problem could be there..

Comment: Your markup is flawed.. you have several <tr><tr> without any </tr> in the beginning. Why do you have hidden input fields a table? They won't be shown on the screen anyway.  Like @ManojSalvi said, we do need the code that handles the submit to be able to see what's going on.

Comment: @ManojSalvi I don´t believe the problem is within the function code because parameters are being sent. The problem is that it just sends the data of the first row in the table(not this table, ofc . Another table that I´ve created before). No matter in which row you click it always sends the data of the first one. But anyway I´ll post the code that handles.

Comment: @ctabuyo - If you don't know what's wrong, how can you exclude any function? And another thing, if this isn't the table that has the problem, why show it to us? Show the code that doesn't work!

Comment: I´m not sure you´re understanding me. Please check my edit, you might understand better then.

Comment: Anyone please? This is driving me crazy :( @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Without knowing what the code looks like it's kind of impossible for us to find the error. Does all the rows have different forms? Are the names of the input fields the same for all rows? Are there the same invalid HTML-markup in the real code as in your example? Without the actual code, how would we know?

Comment: Check my edit I´ll post the whole file... @MagnusEriksson

Comment: First of, remove the inner table. You don't need to structure hidden input fields in a table. Hidden input fields aren't displayed anyway. Secondly, you have the same `id="sbapiform"` on every form. Id's have to be unique. Your `input type="button"`is outside the form.

Comment: Ok, I will. Thank you very much for this @MagnusEriksson

Comment: I have edited the comment. There are a lof of invalid markup.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I deleted the inner table, and moved the input type="button" below all the code, and I´m still having the same issue. Just the data of the first row is being sended no matter in which row button you click.

Comment: Your form id's need to be unique..  and your js-function: `simbriefsubmit()` need to use the correct form.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson What do you mean with id´s need to be unique. I just see these form using the name sbapiform. Thanks heaps!

Comment: No, they use the ID sbapiform. All ID's in HTML must be unique. In your case, your js-function probably fetches the form with the ID sbapiform, which will always return the first it finds in the DOM, the first one. You should read up about HTML.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, OMG it seems you found my problem. because actually the js-function fetches the form with the id sbapiform.... In which way could I fetch it to make it work?

Comment: I need to see the js-code for the `simbriefsubmit()`-function

Comment: Doesn't seem like I can access that file

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, sorry try it now: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ly66ofs566dbsfc/simbrief.apiv1.js?dl=0

Comment: I've added a comprehensive answer on what you need to change to make it work (in theory, since I can't really test it). Try it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your file with the tables, change the for loop to this:

```
<?php
foreach($allroutes as $route)
{
    $formid = isset($formid)? $formid+1 : 1;
```

Further down on your page where you have your button, change it to this:

```
<input type="button" onclick="simbriefsubmit('http://www.virtualaviationgroup.com/index.php/SimBrief', <?= $formid ?>);" style="font-size:14px" value="Generate Flight Plan">
```

...here we added a second argument for the `simbriefsubmit()` call.

Change your form tag to this:

```
<form id="sbapiform<?= $formid?>">
```

...now all forms have unique ID's.

Now we need to add/change a couple of lines in the JS. First on row 742:

```
function simbriefsubmit(outputpage, formid)
{
    if (!formid) 
        var formid = '';
```

...then in the same function, on row 768:

```
do_simbriefsubmit(outputpage, formid);
```

On row 773:

```
function do_simbriefsubmit(outputpage, formid)
{
    if (!formid)
        var formid = '';
```

...row 799 and 804:

```
setTimeout(function(){do_simbriefsubmit(outputpage, formid);},500);
```

...and finally on row 813:

```
var apiform = document.getElementById(sbform + formid);
```

What we have done is to create unique ID for each form and pass the ID to the javascript functions so they can fetch the correct form.

The `if` statements in the functions makes sure that won't break any existing calls to that function.

Comment: I´m afraid it does not work. Now when I click on the button nothing happens.

Comment: this is the error(if you need the file FrontSchedules tell me): https://gyazo.com/3017dc4a3b738ca83d1059fabbdbf42e

Comment: Of course... My bad... I've updated the `<input type="button" .... >`-row in my answer. Update that and try again. :)

Comment: Now I get apiform is null in the console.

Comment: Ok. Missed two places...  updated the answer. It's the line on row 799 and 804 in the js-file you need to update.

Comment: Notice! The line numbers are probably off since you've added rows. You need to find the correct rows (it's the once with `settimeout` were I've only added the `formid`-parameter.

Comment: I don´t understand what you mean @MagnusEriksson

Comment: You have to check the code. The only thing I changed was more or less adding the `formid`-in js-files.

Comment: we have to same problem. Because it just works with the first one I discovered, if the data is different than in the same flight it says Fatal Error: API Key is invalid.

Comment: Do you know why is that? @MangusEriksson

Comment: No. If it complains about the API-key, it seem to be something else.

Comment: I need help. I revised the code but couldn´t find anythiung wrong with it.